# Apache Camel Status Code 401 when send POST Request to PowerBI REST Endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, powerbi

I'm trying to consume a message from a JMS queue using Apache Camel and delivery to PowerBI by endpoint rest.

Below the code:

```
public class FromQueueToPowerBI extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

    Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("java:jboss/exported/FROM.QUEUE");

    from("amq:" + queue.getQueueName())
    .routeId("fromQueueToPowerBI")
    .autoStartup(true)
    .removeHeaders("*")
    .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
    .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
    .log(">>>>>> MESSAGE: ${body}")
    .to("https4:api.powerbi.com/beta/e0...eb/datasets/72...fb/rows?key=fTD...%3D");

}
```

}

I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://api.powerbi.com/beta/e07...feb/datasets/72...5fb/rows?key=fT...3D with statusCode: 401
```

When I try to make this POST by cURL or Postman, working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 401 means "Unauthorized".
You probably have to provide some credentials.

See "`authMethod`", "`authUsername`" and "`authPassword`" parameters in http://camel.apache.org/http.html
Other possibility: directly populate the "Authorization" header:

```
.setHeader("Authorization", constant("Basic xxxxxxxx"))
.to("https4:...)
```

Where xxxxxxxx is "username:password" encoded in Base64

Comment: I contacted the PowerBI Team and they said that this endpoint doesn't have user/password. Using cURL, Postman, SOAPUI, etc, I can handle the POST request with success. Do you know if is there a way to do the same on Camel? Don't use user/password? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried many ways to solve that, but unfortunately with no success.

So, I did a workaround.

I create a Bean with a method doPost(String message).
Instead use .to(), I call this method and the post works fine.

```
.bean(BeanPost.class, "doPost("${body})")
```

Bean:

```
public class BeanPost {

static HttpURLConnection con;

public String doPost(String body) throws IOException {

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("destionation");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Java client");

    try {
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(body);
        httpPost.getRequestLine();
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

        client.execute(httpPost);

        return "OK";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```